# Thread visibility in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

The following code creates a background task and executes it.

```
String dateString = null;
if (dateSelected)
    dateString = Utils.parseDateToMsTimestamp(selectedDate);
final String ori = originCode;
final String dest = destinationCode;
RequestScheduleTask requestScheduleTask = new RequestScheduleTask();
requestScheduleTask
        .execute(ori, dest, dateString);
```

`originCode` and `destinationCode` are instance variables.

The following is what the background task does.

```
private class RequestScheduleTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, List<CUSchedule>> {

    @Override
    protected List<CUSchedule> doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<CUSchedule> cuSchedules = null;

        try {
            cuSchedules = CURestCommunicator
                    .requestSUScheduleByOriginAndDestination(args[0],
                            args[1], args[2]);
        } catch (NetworkException e) {
        }
        return cuSchedules;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<CUSchedule> result) {
        if (result == null) {
            raiseError("Server Error");
        }
        InnoBusApplication innoBusApplication = (InnoBusApplication) getApplication();
        innoBusApplication.setCuSchedules(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

The following is part of what the http call does.

```
public static List<CUSchedule> requestSUScheduleByOriginAndDestination (
        String origin, String destination, String date) throws NetworkException {

    Log.d("upload", "up");

    origin = Utils.shortNameForCity(origin);
    destination = Utils.shortNameForCity(destination);

    HttpClient client = null;

    String url = "http://" + SVR + "/innobussvr/BusSchedulesSearchByOrgDestStartTimeEndTime/"
            + origin + "/" + destination;

    Log.d("url", url);
            ...
}
```

The following is the URL that results.

`http://192.168.0.150/innobussvr/BusSchedulesSearchByOrgDestStartTimeEndTime/null/null`

I understand that this is a thread visibility problem. How can I solve it?

Comment: I mean how did you understand that this due to thread visibility? Can you debug this code in your IDE to see that the flow goes as expected? It's a static call from your `RequestScheduleTask` and if you are indeed setting up/calling your `RequestScheduleTask` properly, this should work. Can you run this through a debugger?

Comment: There's not any thread visibility problem, your code seems ok to me. I'd bet you're losing your strings somewhere, try setting a `Log.d()` line for `origin` and `destination` prior to calling `Utils.shortNameForCity()`.

Comment: Just after calling `requestScheduleTask.execute(ori, dest, dateString);`

I called `Log.d("origin/destination", originCode + "/" + estinationCode);` 

And I am seeing the correct values.

Comment: Probably at that time you still have those values. Try putting a `Log` line before and after the `shortNameForCity` calls.

Comment: @nKn That probably is the cause of my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution just create a Constractor for RequestScheduleTask that takes 2 String and pass them then create inside the Task class 2 local string var.